# How to convert this code to async in Java 8 using CompletableFuture ? I am using Spring Boot

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, asynchronous, completable-future

Here is the Code Snippet that needs to be made async :

```
List<Course> courses = Lists.newArrayList();
Map<String, Map<String, Student>> result = Maps.newHashMap();

for (Map<String, Object> map : jsonObject) {
   courses.add(getCourse(map, fee));  
   result.put(map.get(GROUP), getInfoMap(map));  
}
```

PS : the `map` in the `for-each` loop is not mutated in both the method calls, only the information is used by them.

How can I make the above code run async ? There are two methods being called `getCourse(map, fee)` and `getInfoMap(map)` and it takes quite a time to run them sequentially.

Comment: No they don't mutate the map , they just use the information stored in map @Michael

Comment: Oh I see, I didn't notice the difference between `map` and `infoMap`...

Comment: Edited the question to avoid confusion @Michael

Comment: Would you like to run `getCourse()` in parallel with `getInfoMap()`, run multiple iterations of the loop in parallel, or both? Also, does the order in the `courses` list matter?

Answer (score 0):

```
    // start parallel operations
    List<Future<Course>> coursesFut = Lists.newArrayList();
    Map<String, Future<Map<String, Student>>> resultsFut = Maps.newHashMap();
    for (Map<String, Object> map : jsonObjec t){
        coursesFut.add(CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> getCourse(map, fee)));
        resultsFut.put(map.get(GROUP), CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> getInfoMap(map)));
    }

    // collect results
    List<Course> courses = Lists.newArrayList();
    Map<String, Map<String, Student>> result = Maps.newHashMap();
    for (Future<Course> cf : coursesFut) {
        courses.add(cf.get());
    }
    for (Map.Entry<String, Future<Map<String, Student>> entry : resultsFut.entrySet()) {
        result.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().get());
    }
```